# Unable to install scikit-sparse in Mac M1

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1

I tried to install scikit-sparse in the Macbook Pro M1 max using

`pip install scikit-sparse`

And get the error

> AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp39', 'cp39', 'macosx_11_0_arm64')
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
> Failed to build numpy
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

My suite-sparse is installed.

This is holding up other installations. Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the suitesparse installation causes the problem. If you can use conda, try

```
conda install -c conda-forge suitesparse==5.10.1 scikit-sparse==0.4.8
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge suitesparse
pip install scikit-sparse
```

Both should work fine.